# Regex for url domain

Tags: regex

How do i match from these urls:

```
http://foo.bar.com  
http://bar.com
```

`foo.bar` from the first link and  `bar` from the second link using one single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^http://(.*)\.com$
```

Here's how to use it from Python:

```
import re

for url in ['http://foo.bar.com', 'http://bar.com']:
    print re.match('^http://(.*)\.com$', url).group(1)
```

Output:

```
foo.bar
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your language. In Ruby,

```
>> s = 'http://foo.bar.com'
>> s =~ /\/\/(.*)\./
>> $1
=> "foo.bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you will need to use the same regex as given by Mark Byers, no need to change anything:

```
var p = new RegExp("^http://(.*)\.com");

var out = p.exec(string_var_here);
if(out != null) {
  var str = out[1];
}
```