# Looking to preg replace a domain from a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

What regular expression would one use to remove a domain from a string? I tried several combinations and the closet I come up with works expect removes everything afterwards when a match as been found more than once.

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox <img src="http://domain.com/images/fox.jpg"> jumps over the lazy dog.';
preg_replace('/http:\/\/(.*)domain.com/', '', $string);`
```

Looking detect and remove the following combinations www.domain.com, domain.com and subs.domain.com within an img and href src.

Comment: consider doing a search of stackoverflow for "regex url".  I expect you'll find what you need has already been asked/answered.  This might be what you need, but there are dozens of other similar questions too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923786/regex-for-url-domain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `.*` is greedy. It will consume as many characters as it can to satisfy the match. Put a `?` after it to make it non-greedy like this:

```
preg_replace('/http:\/\/(.*?)domain\.com/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape fullstops ...

```
/http:\/\/[a-z\.]+domain\.com/
```