# get domain from any url

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have these urls

```
http://www.domain.co.uk&affiliate=adwords&ved=0CPsCENEM
http://www.domain.co.uk:affiliate=adwords&ved=0CPsCENEM
http://www.domain.co.uk]affiliate=adwords&ved=0CPsCENEM
http://www.domain.com[affiliate=adwords&ved=0CPsCENEM
```

How can I get the domain from those urls even if I have any character after the TLD?

At the moment I am using the below regex, but this will work only if after the TLD I will have `/`

```
https?:\/\/(?!.*https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,9})
```

Comment: What is your host language/environment that you are running your RegEx in?

Comment: Ruby, I am using the "url".scan(/regex/)

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for url domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923786/regex-for-url-domain)

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's urlparse.

```
import urlparse
s = urlparse.urlsplit('http://www.domain.co.uk&affiliate=adwords&ved=0CPsCENEM').netloc
ind = 0
parts = s.split('.')
if 'www' in parts:
    ind = parts.index('www') + 1
print parts[ind]
```

Answer (score 1):

In comments you told you are using `Ruby`. Having that the urls are stored in `urls.txt` you can follow this example:

```
File.open("urls.txt", "r") do |file_handle|
    file_handle.each_line do |url|
        url =~ /^[^:]+:\/\/((\.?[a-z0-9]+)+)/
        domain = $1
        print "#{domain}\n"
    end 
end
```

**Explanation:**

The regex is based on the fact that any delimiter you might imagine of must at least follow one rule: it is a character which is not allowed in domain or hostnames. The allowed characters in domain or host names are `[0-9a-z-]`. (Note that unicode characters are allowed as well, I don't care about this fact in my answer so far)

```
^              Matches the start of the string
[^:]           Character class. Matches any character except from `:`
+              The previous match needs to occur 1 or more times
:\/\/          The :// after the url protocol
(              Start of outer matching group for the whole domain ($1)
(              Begin of inner matching group. Matches sub domain
\.?            A literal dot. Optionally
[a-z0-9-]+     Sub domain, host name or TLD. At least one character
)              End of inner matching group
+              Endless sub domains but at least one host name are allowed
)              End of outer matching group
```

The domain name will be available via the first capturing group `$1`.

---

**First Answer**

It depends on the regex engine.

The following regex can being used with perl compatible regexes (pcre):

```
grep -ioP '^[^:]+://\K(\.?[a-z0-9]+)+'
```

Having extended POSIX regexes and `awk` you might use:

```
awk -F'(://|[^0-9a-zA-Z.])' '{print $2}'
```

...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
://.*?(\w+)([^\w.]|$)
```

Use group 1 of the match.

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/Zaa7nMZ8kW)